# get key position in onBindViewHolder firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to get key position in database.

getting error: `getRef(position) : Cannot resolve method 'getRef(int)'` on

```
final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
```

this is my code CustomPostAdapter

```
public class CustomPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomPostAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    public List<Spacecraft> userList ;
    public Context context ;

    private boolean mProcessLike = false ;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike ;

  //  public ImageView imagePostt ;

    public CustomPostAdapter(Context context , List<Spacecraft> userList){
        this.userList = userList ;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomPostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_posts_item, parent,false);
        return new CustomPostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
        mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);


        final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

        final String name =  userList.get(position).getName();
        final String image_post = userList.get(position).getImage_post();
        final String descrip = userList.get(position).getDescrip();
        final String hachatg = userList.get(position).getHachtag();
        final String user = userList.get(position).getUser();
        final String time = userList.get(position).getTime();

        //Text Post
        holder.nameText.setText(name);
        holder.descripText.setText(descrip);
        holder.hachtagText.setText(" " + hachatg);
        holder.timeText.setText(" " + time);


        //Imgae Post if null set Visibtly Gone to ImageView
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(image_post)){
            holder.imagePostt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else {
            //Image Post
            Picasso.with(context).load(image_post).into(holder.imagePostt , new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    holder.imagePostt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    holder.imagePostt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }

        //Onclick items
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context , ContentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("NAME_KEY", name);
                intent.putExtra("HACHTAG_KEY", hachatg);
                intent.putExtra("DESCRIP_KEY", descrip);
                intent.putExtra("USER_KEY", user);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGE_POST", image_post);


                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Button Like Onclice
        holder.mLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mProcessLike = true;

                if (mProcessLike){
                    mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                            //Chek if user already Like or not
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(user)){



                            }else {

                                mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(user).setValue("RandomValue");
                                mProcessLike = false;
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }


            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public TextView nameText , hachtagText , descripText, urlText , timeText;
        public ImageView imagePostt ;
        public ImageButton mLikeBtn ;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;


            nameText = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.text_nameProblem);
            hachtagText = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.text_nameUser);
          //  urlText = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textUrl);
            descripText = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.text_Discription);
            timeText = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
            imagePostt = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);
            mLikeBtn = (ImageButton)mView.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);




        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which has the method getRef(). follow [this link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter) to learn how to use it

Comment: i change my code to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter it's work for me thank you ♥

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can solve this. The first one would be to store the `key` as a property in your user object and use:

```
final String key =  userList.get(position).getKey();
```

And the second one would be to simply use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` instead and call:

```
mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getKey(position);
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/262) by @Puf.

Comment: know im trying FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and im using this library `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0'` and the code doesn't show any error but when im trying to run the app in my phone **Application terminated.** deasn't show any errors just **Application terminated.**

Comment: and when i delet this library `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0'` the app run normal

Comment: The fact that you aren't getting anything, sounds as another issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are using wrong dependencies but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question in which you should add both build.gradle files, so me and other users can help you.